# Scrape website not working due to no table found

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape the a website with the below code. But I keep getting a "no table found" error message.

I've tried everything and read every forum.

Can anyone solve this?

```
x=1420110000
url='https://www.weatheronline.co.uk/weather/maps/current?LANG=en&DATE='+str(x)+'&CONT=ukuk&LAND=UK&KEY=UK&SORT=2&UD=12988002&INT=06&TYP=tmax&ART=tabelle&RUBRIK=akt&R=310&CEL=C&SI=mph'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df=df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
df.columns=['Station','Value']
df['Date']=date
```

Comment: This site appears to use dynamic and asynchronous loading for page elements, which means you can't use static HTML for scraping. You probably need to use something like Selenium.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the site is also detecting attempts to automatically access pages, and trying to drive you toward their [data access page](https://dpds.weatheronline.co.uk/historical_data/weather_stations_download/)

Comment: I have tried in my local it is working. They may block you and trying to drive you toward their data access page as @G.Anderson said.

Comment: is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: Possibly, but it may be more trouble than it's worth. You might try finding the information you're looking for on the data access site, or try finding another site with API access or less strict bot-checking